# What does 'How you doing?' by Joey mean?

Tags: analysis, friends

The *'How you doing?'* line of Joey in [**Friends**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/) is very famous. English is my third language. I seem it's general conversation dialogue. What's so special about it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image: Joey] <sup>[[Source](http://timedump.tumblr.com/post/8679051864/how-you-doing-classic-joey)]</sup>

From [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joey_Tribbiani):

> Joey is extremely promiscuous with women, often relying on **his catchphrase pickup line**
>    *"How you doin'?"*.

[[Watch a *How You Doin'?* compilation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMVRAUFqgZU)]

Answer (score 25):

The expression *How you doin'?* is a modification of the English *How are you doing?* which is another way of saying "How are you?".

This phrase seems to be used by stereotypical mobsters in popular culture, who usually were of foreign descent and so would pronounce expressions with an accent. For example, Tony Soprano in the [third season](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Sopranos%3a_Season_3#Another_Toothpick) (the 5th quote in Another Toothpick):

> Tony Soprano: How you doin'? I got new shoes. Soles are a little heavy

Joey does the same (probably a reference to his foreign descent) but in his case, the sentence is a pick-up line, a conversation starter for his die hard promiscuity with women.

Comment: I would say that the phrase is simply a stereotype of NY and NJ machismo culture (of which mobsters were a part).

Comment: I always thought the idea was Joey is so attractive he doesn't have to say anything interesting/funny in order to pick up women.

Comment: @DQdlM What makes you think that's the case?

Comment: @Jac Exactly... Only Joey can pick up women by saying "how are you" :D

Comment: @Alenanno I grew up in NJ and I always associated that phrase (or similar variants) with just the stereotypical NY/NJ male not just mobsters.  Now  if you say it while wearing a fedora and carrying a violin case, that's another story...

Comment: @DQdlM Well, I don't know how much that could be biased considering all the immigrants that have been living there for years. :P What's with the fedora and violin case? lol :D

Comment: @Alenanno definitely true.  I don't know how much this actually happened but [mobsters](http://images.clipartof.com/thumbnails/437126-Cartoon-Gangster-With-A-Gun-In-A-Violin-Case-Poster-Art-Print.jpg) were reputed to carry their tommy guns in a violin case.

Answer (score 15):

As others have pointed out, the phrase in itself is very innocuous and mundane, but it's mostly the **WAY** he says it that adds the flirting overtones. Notice how when he usually says it he narrows his eyes and raises his chin in what he must believe is a seductive look.

I also think it says 2 things about his character:

1. He is not smart enough to think up anything more original
2. And/or he believes he is so good looking he doesn't have to say anything more to attract women

Comment: Well, he did come up with the Europe story.